# Can SO publicise a "Bombing Run" on the Close Votes Queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

**I'm aware that there are lots of posts about the *Close Vote Queue*, which as it currently stands is as a whopping:**

> **118.6k and counting**

The fact it that it's just off putting for people looking to do some real reviewing. When I review something, I truly try to read and understand the review item before casting a decision, hence I probably don't review as much as some people might.

I think there must be numerous people out there that whizz through the queue with the solitary aim of reviewing as many items as possible. The net result will be less constructive feedback to users that have their questions closed.

**Don't get me wrong the reviewing system is good, but surely with one queue that large, it could be better?**

**Promote a Bombing Run**

After seeing the current moderator election in progress, I can see how much prominence can be gained via a "Community Bulletin":

[image]

My main suggestion would be to use this to highlight some form of event (my so called "Bombing Run") that encouraged and possibly rewarded people for helping to get the count down (with some guidance on how to effectively review of course).

This would hopefully attract new reviewers and it could help get those people like me who review now and again to review more frequently.

Give the community a time frame, some targets and make it interactive to show them what they've achieved compared to a normal review period. After all, it's the community that makes SO great and I'm sure it's the community that will help to get this back under control with a little bit of help from you guys behind the scenes.

> [This group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208634/so-close-vote-reviewers-next-meetup-thu-feb-13-400pm-est) already do what I'm suggesting here, but with a
>   community bulletin promoting their effort I'm sure it could be made a
>   very successful recurring event. Thanks to @Troyen for the link.

**DB Cleanse**

My other suggestion would be to do some analysis of the queue via the database. Surely with some intelligent queries I'm sure the queue could be reduced drastically prior to any publicised event. Some queries off the top of my head that could warrant automatic deletion/closing:

1. Any question with *x* number of negative/close votes where the user has only asked a single question and hasn't been on to the site for *y* number of weeks.
2. Any question older than a *x* months with *y* number of negative/close votes and no answers.
3. Any question older than *x* years with no answers

Do SO already do any cleansing I wonder?

Comment: New users already get the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page before asking their first question.  Forcing them to watch the tour won't change much (especially since the tour doesn't go into how to write a _good_ question).

Comment: You can't watch tour and be the same as with experience and rep points.

Comment: There is a group of users that [meet once a week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208634/so-close-vote-reviewers-next-meetup-thu-feb-13-400pm-est) to close questions.  I guess a SO mod could feature that thread to have it show up in the Community Bulletin.  This might be more beneficial after the MSO/MSE split though since it's a SO-specific call to arms.

Comment: @Troyen Just trying to think of ways to get questions from new users to be of a better quality. Most of the time I find that I can google an answer to some questions in 5 seconds.

Comment: I know, but the ask page (either the one above or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)) already suggests that they search first, and they don't.

Comment: @Troyen it's a lot of text though that 9 out of 10 wouldn't read, it would probably be better with a walkthrough of, Good Question vs Bad Question, interactive like the tour

Comment: MB show search results when person firstly formulates a question (as in google instant search)? And to force new users to formulate their question heading 5 times (showing different instant google search results 5 times in a background)?

Comment: @Xsi When I go to ask a new question, I already get a list of questions between the title and the body of question that update based on what I wrote in the title and description.  Half the time I can find my question was already asked and is in that list.  Are you talking about that mechanism or something else?

Comment: @Xsi I understand about the search results when you ask a question, but there are still so many questions that pollute what is otherwise a great resource

Comment: They aren't read in low-resolution monitor or with high browser zoom (poor vision). And BTW there is no experience to pay attention on such many different topics (because you might open them). They are from this site - but not from google, but google is wider (and always will be). And google is suggested **firstly**.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that they like having such a large close vote queue, so that we forget to complain about EVERYTHING else!

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I think this is a case where unilateral closing of low-score content would be helpful. But you can still run out of downvotes.

Comment: Thanks to all the commentators, I've revised the question which has been marked as a duplicate. Even though the main focus of it was for SO to promote an event to look at the queue, I've deleted a few of the side issues in my post.

Answer (score 8):

The close queue is constantly growing because more poor content arrives as the users can close. One of the possible ways to deal with it would be to give stonger closing priviledges to bigger group of users. While increasing the number of moderators will not happen, because SE team thinks moderator to be responsible primarily for handling flags, and not for reviewing, a viable solution could be to give the **single closing vote** to larger groupd of users:

- uniteral close for content with score [-3] or less for [10k] users
- uniteral close for content with negative score, without answers, older than week for [15k] users
- elected for temporary terms (3 months - 1 year) half-moderators, having uniteral close and reopen votes (that could be revoked by other users, so no binding votes)

Another possibility, to encourage stronger to current review model, which isn't working good enough now. What could be done:

- increase close votes and reviews with reputation and/or review history
- refine the interface, for example more clear criteria with shorter names, 'back' button in 'off-topic', single dialog screen for closing
- create new badges for top-reviewers (bronze for monthly, silver for quarterly, gold for yearly)