# Regain daily number of close votes from approved question closures

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Apparently there aren't enough close voters to sanitize the site's quality regarding VLQ and *off-topic* questions.

I am restricted to have a fixed number of close votes in a daily (UTC) scope.

I've noticed that the availability of daily downvotes is somehow floating, regarding time, frequency and successful closure of low quality questions.

Given the fact that a very small community of people is active at doing that kind of essential house keeping at Stack Overflow, **wouldn't it be a good idea that these should regain close voting capabilities** at questions similar as with the downvote statistics?

I am not talking about my *dupe hammer closures*, but just the regular reasons for closing questions, and when they went through, or even lead to deletion of posts.

Here's my [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request):

#### Don't count a close-vote as consumed from the user's maximum UTC-daily allotment of close-votes if:

- **The question is closed within the same UTC day, unless the user closed it as a duplicate using their gold-badge dup-hammer, or**
- **The question is deleted within the same UTC day.**

What would you think about such feature?

Comment: Deletion normally happens at least some days later than the closure, so that would be a problem as votes are given on a daily basis. I don't think the few jit deletions make much of a difference. Neverthless, it would indeed be nice to get CVs back once the question has been closed.

Comment: *"... a fixed number of close votes in a daily scope."* - yeah, chronic problem. We can burn through the daily allotment of votes in 15 minutes for some queues, like the VLQ queue. The site's policy makes no sense. How does one burnout after 15 minutes of review? We really need a policy change. We need unlimited down votes and close votes to combat the increasing flow of crap.

Comment: I, and others, have asked for more close-votes, one way or another, before - they were not forthcoming.  Given how easy it is to use up all close votes, (especially on Sundays), it's not surprising that the queues are the size they are.  Given that, the on-hold latency that assists with the rampant cucumbering and the 100k+ users who care for naught but rep, trying to curate SO seems like a pointless, sisyphean task.  I've stopped bothering.

Comment: @Martin I know about these statistics and experiments. Though I feel overly restricted sometimes.

Comment: @jww Be aware of your wordings plz ;)

Comment: What you're asking for here as a feature is unclear. Please be very specific about exactly what feature you are asking for. For instance, are you asking for a CV to be regained if the question is deleted in the same day? Are you also asking for a CV to be regained if the question is closed, but not by your own dup hammer, in the same day?

Comment: @Makyen What I am asking for is pretty clear IMO: I want to have additional close votes when it turned out my former ones were considered useful and valid throughout a day.

Comment: @Makyen I hope that is specific enough for a FR right now.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow:  The daily limit scales to 50 close votes.

Comment: @Makoto Ooops, maybe I missed that. Though I'd like to behave that more dynamically. Adapted the numbers in my question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - A pot and a kettle are both black.

Comment: @jww My pot is brown mostly (the black stuff is rare and superior), and no ques it's smoked away as quickly you can even turn your head to look back at me ;)

Comment: @MartinJames Ask for rep for close votes.

Comment: @jxh lol, I don't need that much extra rep, expecially any associated with the Sunday Night Specials :)

Comment: How your FR was worded was still unclear to me. I've edited to what I *think* you desire. Obviously, fee free to revert, if you choose.

Comment: Personally, I prefer rather that we expand the gold badge owners close voting power towards other close reasons.

Comment: @MartinJames Although I did intend for you to benefit, but the suggestion was intended to increase close vote participation.

Comment: @Braiam The problem is so widespread that no single suggestion is going to solve it. We'd be best off adopting multiple things, perhaps not all at once, as it would be nice to get an idea for what effects each change has, but SE *really* needs to plan on multiple changes.

Comment: The company is currently focused on bringing in more content by the volume. Suggestions like this have about zero chance of getting implemented, unfortunately.

Comment: I see one major potential problem with this: what if a group of users co-ordinates their votes to close questions for the wrong reasons? If these votes are not counted in their quota, wouldn't it be possible for them to keep closing questions that should not have been?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Well, there's already such loosely coupled   [group](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), but it is established and keeps a strict protocol. Everything else would be thought of a vouting ring fraud, no?

Comment: Do gold tag badge holders consume a CV when they dupehammer?

Comment: @iBug Of course, all the time.

Comment: @iBug And yes of course that would be another nice feature that these should be taken off from the daily count.

Comment: @JJJ More bad content of no value doesn't help in the long term. So that's probably a very bad decision. Ask _@joel_ (saul).

Comment: How about keeping the real crap out of the CV queue in the first place. So implementing some auto-closing mechanism based on X off-topic flags, or VLQ flags. In that way the cases in the gray area can be handled by the CV queue, and the real black stuff can just disappear. The mechanisms are already in place, as happens with spam flags.

Comment: I honestly don't think that more close votes would be all that helpful. Very few people use all of their allowance so the only real solution is to fix the problem and add more abilities like dupe-hammer.

Comment: @DavidG, would be interesting to see some stats about that...

Comment: @Luuklag [Maybe 40 users a day hit the limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353868/how-to-improve-daily-vote-limit-reached-situation#comment497668_353868), allowing them more is essentially a drop in the ocean.

Comment: @DavidG, then adding more votes isnt going to change things around here. Either people need a bigger incentive to CV, or something needs to be done to reduce the influx of posts into the CV queue

Comment: What happens if the post is reopened in the same UTC day?  Does your vote then get counted or did you get a free close vote?

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair point.

Comment: @DavidG But how many users hit that cap and then think "Well I'm not going to bother doing this anymore, since I'll never make a dent in the issue at this rate".

Comment: @DavidStarkey Well that's far harder to measure but I would guess it's not all that much. I think a far, far higher number of people get bored long before hitting the cap for many reasons. 1. It's completely thankless, there is no reward. In fact, it often leads to abuse. 2. Waiting for 5 people to close an egregiously bad question is frustrating, especially when you see answers being added, often by high rep users. My main point still stands, fix the problem, not the sticking plaster

Comment: Slightly related: [Lets burn down the close queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) we just need them to [promote another bombing run](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291957/can-so-publicise-a-bombing-run-on-the-close-votes-queue) on the queues.

Comment: The root of the problem is that we have far too many producers than consumers. Any system with queues only work if the queues are empty at some point. This is basic computer science: if there's not enough processing power to empty the queue at any time, the system will crash, and no amount of queuing will save it. You get a Trash Overflow. The most sensible solution is to prevent as much trash as possible from entering the site in the first place, to minimize the need for manual moderation. And maybe stop antagonizing the veteran users so they don't boycott moderation in turn...

Comment: @jww the review queue limits are in place to *prevent* burnout, so it is only natural that no one would get burned out after maxing out their queue allotment.

Comment: @DavidG I disagree with that argument (or at least have some perspective that Taryn did not mention) and have brought that up in a reply to Taryn's comment. Thanks for linking to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a fair point but how do they currently handle the same system with downvotes for closed/deleted content? If you get a downvote back for a deleted answer and then use it, and the answer gets undeleted, how does the system handle your now extra downvote?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am always for more close votes but I would rather see the CV Queue stop taking up my daily CV allotment; I think there should be a separate stack of those so that we can review 40+ questions in the queue and still have 50 votes for use while browsing organically.

Comment: @TylerH But you say that from the perspective of one of the very few people who might use more CV. OK, so perhaps more people would use more votes, we're still fighting a tsunami with tennis rackets. My point still stands: give us better tools to close/delete questions faster and you won't need to use all your votes. It's already been suggested before (by Shog and others) that if we just blindly add more votes, people get more fed up with the system and burn out. People like you and I want to keep the site clean, I just don't want to do it with countless mind-numbingly boring review queues :)

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I'm not disagreeing with the systemic problem (which is a big one and one that I kinda doubt will ever change), just saying that that one metric you brought up might not be the most solid one as there is a valid argument that can discredit it.

Comment: @NathanOliver If the post is reopened after editing, then close vote served its purpose - it was good close vote. I don't think you will find many posts closed by mistake. And some surplus vote here or there someone might gain would not hurt anyone.

Comment: The number of close voters is much more the limit than the number of close votes per voter. I hardly ever reach the limit close votes, only a few reach that. One could lift the limit but it won't have a significant effect. It may even increase the error rate (at some point you are just exhausted and we don't want robo-reviewers).

Answer (score 11):

I doubt such feature will be implemented. And I doubt it would help in long term.
I agree with your diagnosis:

> Apparently there aren't enough close voters to sanitize the site's quality regarding VLQ and off-topic questions.

It looks like stream of VLQ and off-topic questions increases and the group of close voters decreases. Which is consistent with current StackExchange policy - they do their best to encourage askers to ask questions and they have abandoned veteran users, who work on cleaning the site. [They stop implementing features focused on them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/133648), the main issue for them seems to be ensuring that improving the site quality is done gently enough.

As the trend is: more people asking and less people closing, no matter how many close votes you get, it still won't be enough. If company wants to change this, they need to work on changing this trend (improve tools needed for cleaning the site, make cleaning people feel valued for their work). If they don't want to change it, I think fighting this is pointless. I gave up cleaning. And I think I'm not alone.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't want to see this as a battle already lost. Have we reached the point of no return? :/

Comment: @E_net4, I'm afraid, yes, pretty much. [We've been told SO staff don't take Meta seriously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348). There's also [a history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373464/meta-on-meta-when-to-change-a-discussion-question-to-a-feature-request) of hugely, and almost unanimously, upvoted suggestions which are not being implemented. Reason and effect are aligned here, it's not just a hypothesis.

Comment: Just one correction. The number of askers is not increasing anymore lately. For the last two years, it's kind of remaining constant. I agree though that review activity is in steady decline.

Answer (score -11):

This feature already exists for up- and down- votes. Does it affect the overall voting pattern on Stack Overflow? No, the additional votes made possible by deletion are a drop in the proverbial.

Close voting is like sitting on a committee of five. More close votes = being invited to sit on more committees. Thanks, but no thanks. I'd rather have more influence on the committees where I do participate (like, some closevote weight according to tag scores: a question is closed once the sum of weights of closevotes >= threshold).

But of course, no such system is forthcoming, since the company is far more interested in attracting new "stuck on my Python homework" users than doing anything about quality.

As a wise man [once said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure),

> The current closure system doesn't work. And it is not the limited number of votes. It is the reputation system that encourages people to answer instead of vote.

Comment: _"More close votes = being invited to sit on more committees."_ Well, I could use regained close votes to provide useful duplication using my dupe-hammer privileges, maybe that makes a bit of a difference.